# Configure nest-cli.json to include non TS file into the dist folder

Tags: typescript, compilation, handlebars.js, nestjs, mailer

I'm looking for a solution for several hours now:

I'm creating an email service with nestJS and nest mailer.
Everything work find until I want to include a template with my mail.
Those templates are hbs files located in src/mail/templates
I know that nest doesn't include non TS files when compile so:

I tried to configure the nest-cli.json, following this [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo) added :

```
    "compilerOptions": {
"assets":["**/*.hbs"],
"watchAssets": true,
}
```

OR

```
"assets": [
  { "include": "**/*.hbs","watchAssets": true },
]
```

My nest-cli.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "assets": [
      { "include": "**/*.hbs","watchAssets": true },
    ]
}

}
```

But nothing is copied into the dist folder.
So I solve this with a modification of the package.json, added a cp command to do it manually but I don't think this is the right way do do it...
Is anyone figured out include some non TS files with the assets

PS: hbs is for handlebar (mail templating)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Where are your assets located relative to your code ?

Comment: My assets are in src/mail/templates

Comment: Okay. For information, the "include" is relative to the `sourceRoot` of the project's config in `nest-cli.json`. Could you provide a minimal example of what your `nest-cli.json` looks like ?

Comment: nest-cli.json added above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved by writting the whole path to the file :

```
"assets": [
  { "include": "mail/sendbox/","watchAssets": true },
]
```